# DAX Help (if blank then blank)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am using this formula to Convert Seconds into D:H:M:S but if its blank or 0 i would like the ::: to not show up. any help would be appreciated.

```
2. String AVG Duration = 
var vSeconds=[1. Time Lapse Sec M AVG]
var vMinutes=int( vSeconds/60)
var vRemainingSeconds=MOD(vSeconds, 60)
var vHours=INT(vMinutes/60)
var vRemainingMinutes=MOD(vMinutes,60)
var vDays=INT(vHours/24)
var vRemainingHours=MOD(vHours,24)
return
  vDays&":" &
  vRemainingHours&":"&
  vRemainingMinutes&":"& 
  vRemainingSeconds& ""
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prpY2.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... Return
if ( isblank ([1. Time Lapse Sec M AVG]) || [1. Time Lapse Sec M AVG] = 0
, blank (), vdays&":"&vRemainghours...

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this quite a bit with FORMAT.

```
2. String AVG Duration = 
VAR seconds = [1. Time Lapse Sec M AVG]
VAR days = INT ( seconds / 86400 )
VAR partial = seconds / 86400 - days
RETURN
    IF (
        NOT ISBLANK ( seconds ),
        FORMAT ( days, "0:" ) & FORMAT ( partial, "hh:nn:ss" )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! this works, besides they wand the letters D H M for Day, hour minute to display 0D: 4H: 22M

Comment: Yep, that should be doable with FORMAT too if you tinker with the formatting arguments a bit.